# Cannot generate Spring Boot configuration metadata with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kotlin, gradle

I want to generate Spring Boot configuration metadata, with this way:

[configuration-metadata-annotation-processor-setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor-setup)

In maven, its ok:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

But in gradle, no generated:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

There is same problem with `spring-boot-configuration-processor`, maven is OK but gradle not.

Plugins I used is `java` or `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, not `org.springframework.boot`, but I don't think here is the problem (with plugin `org.springframework.boot`, the problem still exists).

Comment: Did you also do `compileJava.inputs.files(processResources)` in your gradle file?

Comment: @DonHosek Yes, and `compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)`

Comment: @DonHosek Even I run tast `processResources`, no generated in META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Along with the steps you have mentioned you also need to add a class mapping. Something like below.

```
import lombok.Data;    
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.props")
@Data
public class MyProperties {

  /**
   * Prop1 description.
   */
   private String prop1;

   /**
   * Prop2 description.
   */
   private String prop2;
}
```

It's okay to add a class without props but it's needed.

Sample content of resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json

```
{
   "properties": [
      {
         "name": "my.props.prop1",
         "type": "java.lang.String",
         "description": "Prop1 description",
         "defaultValue": "property 1"
      }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get it working in my Kotlin + Spring Boot + Gradle project:

- Rename `src/main/kotlin` to `src/main/java`.
- Use an explicit version for the dependency, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.7.5"
}
```